# Xcode simulator vs my device . Not working right on my device

Tags: ios, iphone, in-app-purchase, ios-simulator

My app using in-app purchase , iap  seeing like this on simulator ;[image]

It's fine working right. But on my iPhone like this ;[image]

What I'm suppose to do ? I want to work right.

Comment: Please [edit[ your question to include an English translation of the message on your iPhone.

Comment: "You need to log in" and asking only password not asking account name. Cancel - Buy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is working fine. When you ran your app in the simulator, you were not yet logged into your iTunes account so iOS asked you whether you wanted to create a new id or use an existing one.

On your iPhone, you were already setup with an id so it simply asked you for our password to that id.

This is all normal and working as expected. If, on the iPhone, you want to see the same message that you see in the simulator, you need to log out of your account. Run the Settings app and go to "iTunes & App Store". Then tap on your Apple ID. An alert appears with different options. Choose "Sign Out". Now when you run your app, you will see the dialog with just like you see on the simulator.

Of course once you log into an account on the simulator (or the iPhone), then you will see just the password dialog in the future.